# Integrating with people soft

Tags: peoplesoft

I want to remotely query peoplesoft and fetch some data given user's credentials match.
Is there a way to do this programatically?
can I do it using python? If not, which language or tech would I need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you can contact the peoplesoft admins, they might be able to provide a webservice which you could then access with python.
If not, you could access the peoplesoft web portal with python using urllib and then parse the html (if the data you need is in a page).

Answer (score 1):

From a purely technical standpoint, PeopleSoft supports web services quite well and could expose the data that way. It's also backended by a database, usually Oracle or SQL Server, which could be potentially attached to directly. Assuming you're working in coordination with a PS developer, web services would be the best route to go.

If you have no other options, you could screen scrape it. Obviously that would be the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Well... it depends what you are trying to achieve.

If you are an admin-type superuser, then the easiest thing to do by far is to query the database itself using SQL.  You don't need the system id for that, rather a read-only SQL user on the database will do just fine most of time.  I do this all the time with Python, mx.ODBC and a good knowledge of the table structure acquired by browsing PSRECDEFN and PSRECFIELDDB.  This is very flexible and powerful, but requires trusting this person and totally bypasses the application's business rules & security.

If you want to log in as a PeopleSoft user, that becomes an entirely different kettle of fish.  You'd have to authenticate using the same OPRID, password and authentication mechanism (direct, single-signon or ldap).  Which would be difficult.  Then you would have no credentials to query the database itself as PeopleSoft does not have 1 db user per application user.

In that case, the web service option would be the way to go.